# removing white space from inported files python

Tags: python

So I importing a file and using that file I am grabbing the numbers ,so I can put it in a list but the white space wont go away this is my code so far. they're some other problem but when that come I will ask you guys.
Thanks.

```
b = []
    opening = open("number.txt",'r')
for a in opening:
    b.append(a.strip())
 opening.close()
 print(b)
```

Comment: Can you show some sample?

Comment: so this is what printed out 

    ['123 321  321 56546 23 135 13 21565684 86213 568']i want to take aways the white spaces

Comment: Are you trying to remove all whitespace or just whitespace at the beginning and end of lines (this is what [`strip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) does)? You may want [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) for this (e.g. `b.append(re.sub('\s', '', a))`.

Answer (score 0):

You're only separating the input by lines.  You need
to further separate it by field:

```
b = []
for a in open("number.txt", 'r'):
    b += a.split()
print(b)
```

If you want the contents of b to be numeric, not strings, use this
line in the for loop:

```
    b += [int(x) for x in a.split()]
```

- Eric

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted 123 to be like 1,2,3

In this case, use the `re` module:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '123'
>>> re.split(r'(\d)', s)[1::2]
['1', '2', '3']
>>> list(map(int, re.split(r'(\d)', s)[1::2]))
[1, 2, 3]
```

Combine this with @thefourtheye's answer for your solution. I will leave it up to you on how to combine it :)

Comment: I deleted mine since OP was not able to explain the problem properly. Please include the list generation part as well :)

Answer (score 0):

[`str.strip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) only removes white-space from either side of a string. Modify your code so that it is like this- instead splitting will effectively extract all of the numerical characters as they are not spaces. [`str.split()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) defaults to having white space as the delimiter:

```
with open('number.txt') as f:
    b = [int(n) for n in [a.split() for a in f.readlines()]]
print(b)
```

That should work.

Answer (score 0):

file = open("number.txt","r")

for line in file:

```
     x=line.split()
     print x
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told us how your file is formatted.

the [csv module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) is pretty good at handling most simple data. You can then call strip on the individual fields.

```
import csv

with open("number.txt", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, skipinitialspace=True)#see docs for configuration
    for row in reader:
        print row
```

As we used a DictReader here each `row` is a dictionary (with keys taken from the first row). You can use the vanilla [csv.reader](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader) if you want a tuple for each row.